# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'PosixPath' and 'str'

Tags: python, opencv

I got an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'PosixPath' and 'str'
```

My code is the following

```
import os
import cv2
import random
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent
path = "../img_folder"

for f in path.iterdir():

    print(f)
    f = str(f)
    img=cv2.imread(f)
    line = random.randint(0, 50)
    img[3, 3, :] = line
    cv2.imwrite(path + "/" + "photo.png", img)
```

Traceback says a code of `cv2.imwrite~` is wrong. I really cannot understand why this is wrong. Is this type of path error? Or am I wrong to use this method? How should I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code? `path` is clearly a string at the start of the for-loop, but you call `iterdir` on it, which AFAIK is not a method on `str` in either Python 2 or 3.

Comment: Assuming that the `path="../img_folder"` does not exist (as noted by @SilvioMayolo) , I believe that `pathlib.Path` returns a `PosixPath` object (not a string).  I don't think you can add these two different objects directly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you look through your type error, it's actually because you're trying to use the `+` operator on a `PosixPath` type and a `str`. You'll need to convert the `PosixPath` to a string before you can use the `imwrite`.

Maybe try:

```
cv2.imwrite(str(path) + "/" + "photo.png", img)
```

Alternatively, use the proper concatenation as described in the [pathlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators).

Comment: Doug's post would be the proper way to do it, although it is nice to know how to convert it to str!

Answer (score 26):

You cannot use operand `+` on a `PosixPath` object. Instead, you should use `/` when dealing with the `pathlib` library:

```
    # before
    cv2.imwrite(path + "/" + "photo.png", img)
    # after
    cv2.imwrite(path / "photo.png", img)
```

Answer (score 7):

First convert the PosixPath object (`path`) to string:

```
str(path) + "/" + "photo.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
cv2.imwrite(str(path) + "/" + "photo.png", img)
```