# Python 3.6 pathlib Path change name parent directory

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

The new Path package from the [pathlib library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which has been added from Python 3.4, seems a powerful replacement of approaches such as `os.path.join()`, but I've some trouble working with it.

I have a path that can be anything from

```
folder_foo/file.csv
```

to

```
long/path/to/folder_foo/file.csv
```

I read the `.csv` file in `folder_foo` with pandas, modify it and want to save it to

```
folder_bar/file.csv
```

or

```
long/path/to/folder_bar/file.csv
```

Essentially I want to rename `folder_foo` to `folder_bar` in the Path object.

EDIT: example path code

```
csv_path = Path("long/path/to/folder_foo/file.csv")
```

## Attempts

#### 1

```
csv_path.parents[0] = csv_path.parents[0] + "_clean")
```

Which leads to the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'PosixPath' and 'str'`, which means you cannot use `+` to combine a `PosixPath` with a `str` as described in [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'PosixPath' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001164/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-posixpath-and-str).

#### 2

To solve this I tried the following:

```
csv_path.parents[0] = Path(str(csv_path.parents[0]) + "_clean")
```

Which however results in the error : `TypeError: '_PathParents' object does not support item assignment`.

Since `PosixPath` is not a list, this error is understandable.

#### 3

Maybe `.parts` is a better approach, but

```
csv_path.parts[-2] = csv_path.parts[-2][:-3] + "bar"
```

results in: `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`.

## Question

How can I easily rename the file's parent folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT: Found a cleaner solution without str()

```
csv_path2 = csv_path.parents[1] / (csv_path.parts[-2][:-3] + "bar") / csv_path.parts[-1]
# result
PosixPath('long/path/to/folder_bar/file.csv')
```

`Path.parents` gets the whole path to the folder minus the file. `Path.parents[1]` goes 2 levels up (`long/path/to/`), which is still a Path object. Then we get the last folder name with `csv_path.parts[-2]`, which is a string. We apply `[:-3]` to get all string characters except `"foo"`. This means we have `"folder_"`. Then with `+ "bar"` we get `"folder_bar"`, which is added to our `Path` object. Finally we re-add the file name to our `Path` object with `/ csv_path.parts[-1]`.

## Hack like solution

```
csv_path = Path(str(csv_path.parents[0])[:-3] + 'bar/' + csv_path.parts[-1])
```

It seems to me a bit unintuitive, however. There should be a more clean solution?

Comment: The cleaner solution is definitely writing a function like suggested by hume, then using the function.

Answer (score 9):

Would rather split this up for readability:

```
bar_folder = csv_path.parent.parent / 'folder_bar'
csv_path2 = bar_folder / csv_path.name
```

Having the destination folder as a variable also enables you to create the folder using for example:

```
bar_folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also write a little function to replace the part of the path you want to change. Here's a runnable example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path1 = Path("a/b/c.txt")
path2 = Path("b/c.txt")

def rename_dir(path, src, dst):
    # convert to list so that we can change elements
    parts = list(path.parts)
    
    # replace part that matches src with dst
    parts[parts.index(src)] = dst
    
    return Path(*parts)

rename_dir(path1, 'b', 'q')
#> PosixPath('a/q/c.txt')

rename_dir(path2, 'b', 'q')
#> PosixPath('q/c.txt')
```

<sup>Created at 2021-03-06 10:44:00 PST by [reprexlite](https://github.com/jayqi/reprexlite) v0.4.2</sup>